# How can I search for all questions but exclude specific tags?

Tags: support, search

I need to search questions by the newest first, but exclude questions I know nothing about.

In order to do this I tried `-[google-apps-script]-[javascript]`, but it instead searches for questions that have those tags.

How can I search all questions except those which have certain tags?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange Meta!

Comment: It is not a duplicate, lol.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, my answer was not properly answered, this "a" "the" hack is not a solution.

Comment: Why you edit questions more than actualy answer them?

Comment: This was closed as a duplicate because it was very similar to the other question linked at the top of the page. See meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/… for more info. I don't think what you were trying to ask is actually a duplicate, so I edited your question to make it more clear what you were asking. Editing also adds the question to the reopen queue, where other people vote to reopen it or not.

Comment: See my question for a better solution.

Comment: This solution is good, thank you. I probably can explore some questions now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have found the solution.

If you go to your profile and click on the `edit profile and settings` button (labelled **1** on the image) you will see a button called `preferences` (I labelled it **2**). Click on it, and at the bottom of the page you will see `ignored tags` (**3**). See the image below:

[image]

Place the tags that you want to exclude in the box and click `hide questions in your ignored tags`. It is done! You will never be shown those questions again.

Comment: Wish it worked without "overflow".

Comment: @Vibok are you trying to search every question except ones with those tags?

Comment: yes. I guess I should filter them on my side instead then.

Comment: accepted, though it's an ugly solution. But whatever.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that a search string does not work as expected when all terms have a hyphen.

Try these on this site:

- `overflow -[search] -[support]` creates the URL https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=overflow+-%5Bsearch%5D+-%5Bsupport%5D and finds nearly 18,000 results
- `-[search] -[support]` creates the URL https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=-%5Bsearch%5D+-%5Bsupport%5D and finds 0 results

Comment: I guess it is a bug then. It is very common for sites to not allow properly "exclude only".